# Cannot override Hibernate lazy fetching with fetch-profile OR hibernate.initialize()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple scenario in many places in my webapp - when showing a list of objects, I don't want to query ALL the details (ie child objects), but when I show the user a single object for them to edit, I DO want to query the entire object. So I let Hibernate default to lazy-fetching these child objects for getting the list, and want to override that with fetch = JOIN at runtime. I tried 2 methods, both of which should work but dont!

Here is my mapping file :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="User">
        <id name="objectId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Object_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="address" class="Address" cascade="save-update" >
            <column name="Address_ID" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        ... other User properties ...
</hibernate-mapping>
```

First, I tried querying the default lazy User object, and then using Hibernate.initialize() to load the lazy child object :

```
User user = session.get(User.class, (Serializable) id);

if ( !Hibernate.isInitialized(user.getAddress()) )
    Hibernate.initialize(user.getAddress());
}
```

Hibernate recognized that the child Address object wasnt loaded but initialize() STILL didn't load the Address. Why?

Next I tried a fetch-profile, by adding this to the Hibernate mapping file :

```
<fetch-profile name="returnEntireUser">
    <fetch entity="User" association="address" style="join"/>
</fetch-profile>
```

And then using the code:

```
User u1 = session.get(User.class, (Serializable) id);
session.enableFetchProfile("returnEntireUser"); 
User u2 = session.get(User.class, (Serializable) id);
```

And both u1 and u2 objects are the same - both without the Address object filled in. I know Hibernate recognizes the fetch profile, but still doesnt do anything.

Can anyone figure out WHY these methods dont work and what I can do to get them to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I feel a little bit stupid. Both of the above methods DO actually work, however you will NOT see the results in an Eclipse debugger session. In another section of code I used Criteria and the

```
setFetchMode("field",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

method and in this case the debugger object DOES contain all the data, so I expected to see the full object in the debugger using the above strategies, but it didn't happen.

Also for ohers to note you cannot run test cases in the code back to back on the same object because of Hibernate caching the object. The debugger might or might not show anything meaningful.